# Which style of Django Rest Framework should I be using

Tags: django-rest-framework

(I'm using the latest django/python/DRF)

My API endpoints are application internal. They do not match 1-to-1 to models I have in the system. I've seen two techniques of using views for APIs.

The first uses methods, like I'm using:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])
def myApiEndPoint(request):
    """
    This text is the description for this API.
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response("ok get", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return Response("ok post", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The second uses class definitions, like the DRF documentation

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

The second way seems more neat and orderly. But:

1. Can I use it for validations that aren't model specific?
2. How do I define the per-class permission and authentication classes in this instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes

   - create serializers based on `Serializer` (not `ModelSerializer`) and the put your custom validations for fields there
   - instead of using `ModelViewSet` as your base class use `viewsets.GenericViewSet` for `GET` create a method named `list` and for `POST` create a method named `create` for more info check viewset [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
2. it's very simple:

simply define these vars in your viewset: (also check docs for [authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and [permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

```
class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ] # or any other permission class
    authentication_classes = [JSONWebTokenAuthentication, ] # or any other authentication class
```